# Can't pip install pyAudio in conda environment (MAC)

Tags: python, macos, pyaudio

I am using a conda enviroment on mac and I want to install pyAudio.
I tried to follow the suggestion in many threads to run

```
brew install portaudio
```

r

```
pip install --global-option='build_ext' --global-option='-I/usr/local/include' --global-option='-L/usr/local/lib' pyaudio
```

But it still didn't work from **within** the conda enviroment. However, running

```
pip install --global-option='build_ext' --global-option='-I/usr/local/include' --global-option='-L/usr/local/lib' pyaudio
```

worked outside of the conda enviroemtn (in the "base" enviroemtn").

What might be the reason? How can I install pyAudio inside the conda enviroment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `conda install -c anaconda pyaudio`

Source: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pyaudio

Answer (score 1):

`portaudio` is not a python package. The easiest solution would be use the pyaudio conda package from this place https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pyaudio

You can try the following commands to install pyaudio inside conda (after activating your conda environment).

`conda config --add channels conda-forge`

`conda install pyaudio`

Answer (score 0):

**find your Python version by python --version mine is 3.7.3 for example**

**the easiest way to check either you have 64 or 32 Python just open it in the terminal:**

**find the appropriate .whl file from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio), for example mine is**

**PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl, and download it.**

**go to the folder where it is downloaded for example cd C:\Users\foobar\Downloads
install the .whl file with conda for example in my case:**

```
conda install PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

link source  [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio)

Or try this if you already download whl

```
conda install -c anaconda pyaudio
```

link source[here](https://github.com/conda-forge/pyaudio-feedstock)

Answer (score 0):

From the anaconda.org they recommend this pyaudio 0.27:

```
conda install -c mutirri pyaudio
```

otherwise for pyaudio 0.2.11 this one:

```
conda install -c anaconda pyaudio
```