# Getting error in installing in PyAudio module

Tags: python, python-3.7, python-3.8, pyaudio

After trying countless times I still cannot install PyAudio without getting this error

I have tried using many approaches including pipwin which doesn't get recognized as a real function, how can I install PyAudio?

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\person\person\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\person\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-csmluknr\\pyaudio_4df1e1a74cd34515a3cf4ed28ceefeae\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\person\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-csmluknr\\pyaudio_4df1e1a74cd34515a3cf4ed28ceefeae\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\person\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-tj523gnc\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\person\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\Include\PyAudio'
         cwd: C:\Users\person\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-csmluknr\pyaudio_4df1e1a74cd34515a3cf4ed28ceefeae\
    Complete output (17 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 "-IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include" "-IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
    _portaudiomodule.c
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\pyconfig.h(117): warning C4005: 'MS_WIN64': macro redefinition
    src/_portaudiomodule.c: note: see previous definition of 'MS_WIN64'
    src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.27.29110\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\person\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\person\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-csmluknr\\pyaudio_4df1e1a74cd34515a3cf4ed28ceefeae\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\person\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-csmluknr\\pyaudio_4df1e1a74cd34515a3cf4ed28ceefeae\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\person\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-tj523gnc\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\person\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\Include\PyAudio' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download PyAudio wheel file from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio).

Then use `pip install XXX.whl` to install.

For example: `pip install E:/PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl`

You can check how many bits your computer is, and then download the corresponding wheel.
`PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl` supports python3.7 for windows 64-bit system.
`PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl` supports python3.7 for windows 32-bit system.

Comment: So which wheel package would I have to download for python 3.7?

Comment: I have updated my answer,you can download wheel from new link.`PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl` is for 64-bit system.`PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl` is for 32-bit system.

Comment: Yes thank you, downloading the wheel package first fixed the installation error :)

Answer (score 1):

You can install PyAudio by first installing:

```
pip install pipwin
```

Wait until it's done, then:

```
pipwin install pyaudio
```

It will work for people who have Python 3.9.

Answer (score 0):

If Anaconda is installed, we can also use the conda installation tool to install the module "`PyAudio`" in VSCode: (`conda install PyAudio`)

[image]

Reference: [Environment in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment).

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion by Aman above works for me, within the Anaconda3 environment, using the Anaconda3 Prompt.

First run this:

```
pip install pipwin
```

Then run this:

```
pipwin install pyaudio
```

Prior to this, I did install the [Microsoft Visual Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/). It DID NOT help.

Similar issue found in previous [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61064506/cant-pip-install-pyaudio-in-conda-environment-mac).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site doesn't operate like a message board. Please don't post new answers as commentary, as a way of saying "thank you", or to validate existing answers. In this case, **you're mostly just repeating the accepted answer**. The only thing that's unique is a comment about something you tried that did _not_ work. Later, with a bit more reputation, you'll be able to upvote answers you found useful as a way of validating them.